# Build HttpServletRequest from predefined data

Tags: java, http

For testing I want to build `HttpServletRequest` object from some predefined data, something like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/
12.01
Host: www.foo.com
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png,
image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap;q=0.1
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

And also setup url and client address. Is there some simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kirill! I think the best way in your case is using [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html) framework.
For example, you can make mock of HttpServletRequest interface. And use:

```
   HttpServletRequest httpRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
   Mockito.when(httpRequest.getHeader("Host")).thenReturn("http://www.foo.com");
   Mockito.when(httpRequest.getHeader("Referer")).thenReturn("blalba");
   Mockito.when(httpRequest.getHeader("User-Agent")).thenReturn("Opera");
   Mockito.when(httpRequest.getRemoteAddr()).thenReturn("127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a parse to read the predefined data and use HttpClient to send requests as per your requirements.

[HttpClient Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/)